# debug Linux process with suid

Tags: linux, unix, permissions

I develop an application with requires root privileges. I use Code:Blocks launched with `sudo codeblocks` command. The problem is that developing in root'ed Code::Blocks results in source files and CB configuration files being created with root owner.

I thought I could use setuid on codeblocks executable but it is not allowed with GTK apps.

Is there other ways to elevate effective UID of the programs under debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most simple solution to debug programs which need root privileges is to run the debugger as root.